# How to add theme dynamically to chip view android

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components, android-chips

i have chip group in **xml** layout and need to add chip **dynamically**.  i need to add **theme** dynamically ,without changing the app theme i want to set material theme for chip view till now i cant find a proper solution , i will show my code snippet. i need your help badly

```
Chip chip = new Chip(mContext);
        chip.setCloseIconVisible(true);
        chip.setText(dataOptions.getListTitle());
        chip.setTextAppearance(mContext, R.style.button_style_value_color_black);
        chip.setHeight(30);
        chip.isCloseIconVisible();
        chip.setChipStrokeColorResource(R.color.chip_stroke_color);
        chip.setChipStrokeWidth(1f);
        chip.setCloseIconTintResource(R.color.grey_500);
        chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.chip_background);
        chip.setChipCornerRadius(10f);
        mBinding.feNotesChip.addView(chip);

   chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAdapter.setItemToTheList(dataOptions, mBinding.feNotesEt.getText());
                mBinding.feNotesChip.removeView(chip);
                dataOptionsList.remove(dataOptions);
                saveToFormElement(dataOptionsList, newList);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use this [constructor](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip.java#L189) and pass in the `style`

Comment: @sonnet the 3rd parameter is **not** a style. It is just the attribute in the app theme.

Answer (score 0):

Using this library (https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView)
You can extend from their `Adapter` (i.e., `ChipViewAdapter`) and override the methods needed, I used to change backgrounds on specific conditions

```java
    @Override
    public int getBackgroundRes(int position) {
        if (chipList.get(position).getChipType().equalsIgnoreCase(AppConstants.LOCATION)) {
            return drawable1;
        }
        return drawable2;
    }
```

Comment: But why a 3rd party library?

Comment: Was proposed by client. So, I used this.

Comment: Ok, but did you read the question? The question is not what library can I use for a Chip.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I did not say you have to use the library I mentioned, I just told you this is how I did it using library